# Lock a file while retaining the ability to read/append/write/truncate in the same thread?

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

I have a file containing, roughly speaking, the state of the application.

I want to implement the following behaviour:

- When the application is started, lock the file so that no other applications (or user itself) will be able to modify it;
- Read the previous application state from the file;
- ... do work ...
- Update the file with a new state (which, given the format of the file, involves rewriting the entire file; the length of the file may decrease after the operation);
- ... do work ...
- Update the file again
- ... do work ...
- If the work failed (application crashed), the lock is taken off, and the content of the file is left as it was after the previous unit of work executed.

It seems that, to rewrite the file, one should open it with a `Truncate` option; that means one should open a new `FileStream` each time they want to rewrite a file. So it seems that behavior I want could only achieved by such a dirty way:

- When the application is started, read the file, **then** open the `FileStream` with the `FileShare.Read`;
- When some work is done, close the handle opened previously, open another `FileStream` with the `FileMode.Truncate` and `FileShare.Read`, write the data and flush the `FileStream`.
- When some work is done, close the handle opened previously, open another `FileStream` with the `FileMode.Truncate` and `FileShare.Read`, write the data and flush the `FileStream`.
- On the `Dispose`, close the handle opened previously.

Such a way has some disadvantages: extra `FileStream` are opened; the file integrity is not guaranteed between `FileStream` close and `FileStream` open; the code is much more complicated.
Is there any other way, lacking these disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't close and reopen the file.  Instead, use [FileStream.SetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx)(0) to truncate the file to zero length when you want to rewrite it.

You might (or might not) also need to set FileStream.Position to zero.  The documentation doesn't make it clear whether SetLength moves the file pointer or not.

Comment: `FileStream.SetLength` is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take exclusive access to the file when application starts, and create an in-memory cache of the file that can be shared across all threads in the process while your actual file remains locked for OS. You can use lock(memoryStream) to avoid concurrency issues. when you are done updating the local in-memory version of file just update the file on disk and release lock on it.

Regards.

Comment: It seems that you misunderstood the question. I want to "update file on disk" on each _checkpoint_ (so that if the application crashes later, all the data up to the latest checkpoint will be stored on the disk). The question is: how can I (multiple times) rewrite the file without releasing the lock? The problem is, in fact, not related to threading; i just thought that stating the question in such a way will make it easier to understand.

Comment: sorry i misleaded by the title of your question. so you want to push updates to the file on disk periodically but don't actually wants to release the lock on file so that other process should not modify the file while your process is running?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Also, the _update_ is not the appending to an existing file, but rather rewriting the entire file contents (so that the new content might be shorter than the original one).